# Writing a hash for output data to JSON

Tags: json, perl

I need to output JSON from a perl program in a certain format. The catch is there's a loop involved. 
Here's the format:

```
{"data":[
  {
    "data_point":"1"
  }
  {
    "data_point":"2"
  }
]}
```

This works with no loop:

```
$data = {"data" => [{"data_point" => "1"}, {"data_point" => "2"}]};
open my $fh, ">", "data.json";
print $fh encode_json($data);
close $fh;
```

How do I get this to work in a loop?

```
@list = (1,2);
foreach $number (@list) {
  $data = ?
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a hashref, with the sole key's value being an arrayref, containing hashrefs as elements.

```
my @list = (1..2);

my $data->{data} = [ map { { data_point => $_ } } @list ];

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $data;
```

The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) builds the list of hashrefs `{ data_point => $_ }`, that is made into an arrayref by `[ ]`, which is then assigned as the value to the key `data`.

We may omit `''` for keys by the courtesy of `=>` operator, since its left-hand-side argument is treated as quoted. So `data` works the same as `'data'`.  See [Comma operator in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator).

This makes what you ask, what is checked using [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html). For more keys than just `'data'` you can put the line in a loop, and for varied data description strings can use a sub inside `map`.

Answer (score 0):

From list you create array of hashes (1). Then you put that array into another hash (2):

```
my @list =  ( 1..2 );
my @data;
push @data, { data_point => $_ }   for( @list );  # (1)

my $result =  { data => \@data };                 # (2)
```

Hash may contain only scalar values and it can not contain arrays. So here we store reference of our array: `\@data`